# How to pass additional parameters when Func<t, t> is the required type?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have two relevant static methods in UserModel:

```
public static UserModel GetUserByUsername(String username)
{
    //do something
    return UserModel;
}
```

and an overload:

```
public static UserModel GetUserByUsername(String username, DateTime date)
{
    //do something else
    return DiffUserModel;
}
```

Right now, I can successfully select a

```
List<UserModel>
```

by running

```
... .Select(UserModel.GetUserByUsername)
  .ToList();
```

This is calling the overloaded method:

```
public static UserModel GetUserByUsername(String username)
```

**QUESTION:**

How can I call the overloaded method and pass in a `DateTime` parameter using similar syntax?

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
... .Select(UserModel.GetUserByUsername , DateTime.Now)
      .ToList();
```

to get a List generated from the overloaded method.

Comment: Method delegates cannot be partially applied - use lambdas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), a type of [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx):

```
.Select(x => UserModel.GetUserByUsername(x, DateTime.Now))
```

Comment: Actually, anonymous methods were added to C# before lambda expressions.  They are both a way to create inline functions but lambda expressions have a simpler syntax that anonymous methods.

Comment: That's awesome and now I finally get Lambda expressions vs. delegates. A follow on quesiton: How can I pass an existing date time object? I am getting a `The name '...' does not exist in the current context?

Comment: @JSKNS Yes you can, as in `var someDate = DateTime.Now; var result = list.Select(x => UserModel.GetUserByUsername(x, someDate)`. I'm not sure why you're getting that error, and without seeing the code, it's hard to say what this issue is.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, lambdas are type of anonymous method. I didn't mean to imply that they are synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't say that one method is overloaded and one is not.  That method name is overloaded and both methods are overloads.

As for the question:

```
.Select(new Func<UserModel, string>(s => UserModel.GetUserByName(s, DateTime.Now)))
```

Comment: Fair note. How would you better differentiate?

Comment: If you're asking how to differentiate overloads then the answer is exactly as the system does: by the number and type of the parameters.  I would probably refer to those two methods as the overload with one parameter and the overload with two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternate solution, since you seem to like method groups:

`.Zip(Enumerable.Repeat(DateTime.Now, whatever.Count), UserModel.GetUserByName)`

Will probably do the same thing. It's a slightly awkward use of repeat, but it does end up rather simple.